# Bootstrap submit form displayed from javascript timer

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timer, delay, form-submit

I'm trying to create a modal form that is displayed from javascript with a delay.

When I start the modal form with a button (onClick event) the parameters are submitted to the form correctly but when the form is displayed from the timer (with setTimeout) the modal form is displayed but the parameters are not passed to the form. Both cases are in the example below. Any help/links is much appreciated. I just can't figure out what is the difference in the two options:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
  <link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
  <body>
  Main Page

<div id="thanks"><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content" class="btn btn-primary">Contact us</a></p></div>

    <!-- model content -->    
    <div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
            <div class="modal-header">
                  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                  <h3>Contact us</h3>
            </div>
        <div>
            <form class="contact">
            <fieldset>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">Name</li>
  ...
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">submit</button>
             <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          </div> </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      timeTriggeredModal();//
    }, 300); // milliseconds
});

//>>>This does not work <<<<<<
function timeTriggeredModal() {
$('#form-content').fadeIn(300)(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
             url:    "process.php",
            data:    $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                       // $("#thanks").html(msg)
                          $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
                 },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
           });
    });
};

//>>>>>>>>This works<<<
 $(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
             url:    "process.php",
            data:    $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                       // $("#thanks").html(msg)
                          $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
                 },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
           });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See example at: http://www.heartlink.co.uk/heartlink/test4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you want to write this is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {  
      $("#form-content").modal('show'); //this will show your modal
    }, 300); // milliseconds

    $("button#submit").click(function(){ //this will handle the form submission upon clicking the submit button
            $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
             url:    "process.php",
            data:    $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                       // $("#thanks").html(msg)
                          $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
                 },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
           });
    });
});
</script>
```

The setTimeout could call a separate function to display the modal, but you can't just randomly pass an ajax function to the fadeIn function because that function is designed to run when the animation is complete (which wouldn't give users any opportunity to fill in the form).  Even so, when you use the complete function in the fadeIn method, you separate the duration of the fade in behavior from the complete function with a comma not as you have it in parenthesis (just FYI).

Moreover, while fadeIn can work, Bootstrap has its own methods for showing and hiding modals.  It's probably easier to just use the `.modal('show')` method as shown in the code above.

Your click handler will take care of the form submission no matter how the form was displayed, so you don't have to worry about duplicating the ajax call.